# Is it possible to have something that displays the filenames of all my unfocused windows?

Tags: vim-windows

Both the statusline and the tabline only show the file I'm currently working (on on my current tab). Is there any built-in setting that can show the names of the files that occupy the windows I'm not currently focused on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any built-in setting that can show the names of the files that occupy the windows I'm not currently focused on?

I suppose you mean `set laststatus=2`. That makes every window to have a status line of its own (which by default also shows a file/buffer name).

Beyond this, many customizations are possible, but they all require quite a bit of scripting (or plugin use).

Comment: thank you. for some reason I missed that. I was using a vertical split and maybe I thought I was seeing a single status bar, who knows. Is it possible to make the status bar not show up on the active window?

Comment: @Mason No, status lines could only be switched off globally (`set laststatus=0`). At the best, you can create an empty local status line with a background color, but it will still consume screen space, and I don't see any good reason to do so.